# How to change seperated value in CSVImporter (Swift)

Tags: swift, excel, xcode, csv

I have a .csv data and I want my Swift program to read it.
But as I am German and the German excel makes the csv data not comma seperated; it makes it semicolon-seperated (;). And as my data has mich commas, I don't find it bad.

But my csv importer https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter works comma seperated, so he doesn't seperate when I want (by semicolons); he seperates at the commas in the text.

It is possible to change this? Can you say me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the README: https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter#basic-csv-import

It states you can specify an alternative delimeter. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter/blob/stable/Sources/Code/CSVImporter.swift#L82), the second argument, `delimiter` accepts a string and is what you would want to use to specify an alternative delimiter.

Modifying the example code under "Basic CSV Import", we can use the following:

```
let path = "path/to/your/CSV/file"
let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: path, delimiter: ";")
...
```